# Socket.io and Redis broadcast to all clients except sender

Tags: node.js, laravel, redis, socket.io, broadcast

I use Laravel in back-end to make a chat app. but when I use `redis`, I can't use `broadcast.send` function. Now how to send message to all client except sender? This code has error:

> io.broadcast.send(channel + ':' + message.event, message.data);

It's all my server code:

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var Redis = require('ioredis');
var redis = new Redis();


redis.subscribe('chat');

redis.on('message', function(channel, message) {
    console.log('Message Recieved: ' + message);
    message = JSON.parse(message);

    // send all client except sender
    io.broadcast.send(channel + ':' + message.event, message.data); 

});


io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {      
    console.log('User Connect with ID: ' + socket.id);         
});

// run server
http.listen(3001, function(){
    console.log('Listening on Port 3001');
});
```

and client code:

```
var socketClient = io(':3001');
socketClient.on("chat:App\\Events\\ChatEvent", function(message){
        // increase the power everytime we load test route
        console.log(message);       
    });
```

ChatEvent.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Events;

use App\Events\Event;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;

class ChatEvent extends Event implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use SerializesModels;

    public $message;

    public function __construct($value)
    {
        $this->message = $value;
    }


    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return ['chat'];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could extend the **emit()** function with an additional argument, say **send_to_self=True**, which along with **broadcast=True** or a room value will configure if the current client should be included or not. By default things will remain the same, but if send_to_self is set to False, then the loop that iterates over all the clients to notify will skip the current connection. To detect which one is the current one you can use request.namespace, which is the namespace object for the active client.

So your code is

```
io.emit(channel + ':' + message.event, message.data,send_to_self=false);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use helper broadcast to do this and then using method `toOthers()`;
more details go to docs https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/broadcasting#only-to-others

Answer (score -1):

Try using wildcard

```
class messageEvent extends Event implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use SerializesModels;

    public $userid;

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($user)
    {

        if($user==\Auth::guard('admin')->user()->id){
                  return false;
         }
        $this->userid = $user;


    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should be broadcast on.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function broadcastOn()
    {   
        return ['ChatEvent-'.$this->userid];
    }
}
```

In Js make a change

```
    var socketClient = io(':3001');
    socketClient.on("chat:App\\Events\\ChatEvent-<?php echo \Auth::guard('admin')->user()->id; ?>", function(message){

            console.log(message);       
        });
```

Comment: Thanks @ronak , but I think you don't understand my means. I want to broadcast message to all clients except sender with socket.io server configuration.

Comment: @Ehsan 
"if($user==\Auth::guard('admin')->user()->id)"
in this condition the event will be fired with sender and the sender will be ignored with this condition..